# What is the use of stderr=subprocess.STDOUT in subprocess.check_output()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code in Python that is supposed to run some commands. To do this I'm using subprocess.check_output() as it allows to have a timeout. 
I understand how it works and what parameters we are supposed to give to it however I saw online that people are using "stderr=subprocess.STDOUT" a lot and I was wondering what it does and if I should use it or not.

I'm using Python 3.7

Here is an example of code:

```py
import subprocess as sp

out = sp.check_output("ls not_existing_folder", 
                      stderr=sp.STDOUT, 
                      universal_newlines=True, 
                      timeout=15)
```

So I tried running it with and without the "stderr=sp.STDOUT" line but it doesn't appear to change anything. I saw online that it's supposed to catch the error message, preventing a display in the console. I'm not sure I got that right... Can someone explain me the use of this piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reporting it as an error as normal, it just prints it to the console as standard output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question is, should I use it or not? What does it change for my code if I don't have it?

Comment: From what I've gathered, it's similar to logging, or used for that purpose. In fact, if you want a full logger, that could be pretty important. But without it, the only real difference is you won't have log messages fill your terminal.

Comment: Perhaps add an example of what is wrong, and how to fix it via code